# can we programatically set to which tabar item should be displayed when a tab bar is shown?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am working on a project which contain a tab bar. The tab bar contain 2 items named leave and Od. Both are normal viewcontroller class. They have a table view inside it(I dont mean table view controller). While clicking on a item in a table view a pop Up screen appears which  have a viewcontroller swift file named as popUpviewController. This show details of item selected in table view. The problem is when i dismiss the popUpdialog i always get the selected tabBar item as the default one.Here its leave authorise.

[image]

what I did is i gave an Storyboard Id to tab Bar controller and called it from the popUp when its dismissed, like this.

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name:self.whichSB!, bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AuthoriseTabBar?") as UIViewController
                    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex=2  /* DOESN'T WORK OBVIOUSLY*/
                    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

**   The tab bar controller doesn't have any associated class with it.I would like to show item 1 when item1 popUp is dismissed(This works as its now the default item shown in tab bar), and item 2 when item 2 popUp is dismissed.**

Can anyone suggest a away of doing the above . and I havent used any navigation controller here, is it necessory to get tabbar.selectedindex of tab bar

Answer (score 0):

You can access the tab bar, from the popup VC, like this. Just run this with the normal dismiss line as shown.

```
if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController {
        if let tabController = presentingVC.tabBarController {
            tabController.selectedIndex = 0 // Whatever index you want to select.
        }
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```